# O uso do operador "and" nesse código está correto? Pois não está funcionando

Tags: node.js, sequelize-js

A função desse código é receber os dados de login através das `req` e fazer com consulta para ver se os registros existem e o usuário pode acessar determinada area, mas o código abaixo não estar indiferente tanto quanto digito os dados corretos no formulário, quanto digito os dados errados no formulário.

```js
routeradmin.post('/envlogin', function (req, res) {
  dadoslogin.findAll({
    where: {
      email: req.body
         senha: {
        [Op.and]: req.body.senhauser
      }

    }, raw: "true"
  }).then(
    function () {
      res.send("deu certo");
    }).catch(function (error) {
      res.send("deu errado");
    });
});
```

Como a consulta na minha visão iria retornar o valor ou não, usei `.then` e `.cacth` para processar as hipóteses de resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo visto você deseja fazer uma consulta que resulta no `AND` para verificação de `senha` e `email`, ou seja, a consulta SQL que você espera seria algor do tipo:

```sql
SELECT * FROM post WHERE email = 'teste@email.com' AND senha = '123';
```

Nesse caso deveriamos fazer o seguinte:

```js
routeradmin.post('/envlogin', function (req, res) {
  dadoslogin.findAll({
    where: {
    [Op.and]: [ // usamos o "Op.and" dessa forma
      { email: req.body },
      { senha: req.body.senhauser }
    ]
  }, raw: "true"
  }).then(
    function () {
      res.send("deu certo");
    }).catch(function (error) {
      res.send("deu errado");
    });
});
```

dessa forma o Sequelize inferiu que queremos um `AND` para as duas verificações (`email` e `senha`), isso gera:

```sql
SELECT * FROM post WHERE (email = 'teste@email.com') AND (senha = '123');
```